# Missing "to" in perks of working for Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammatical-correction

In the perks section of working in Stack Overflow it states the following:

"And much more such as Summer Fridays, a subscription Calm, and others!"

Should it say "...a subscription to Calm..." ?

[image]

https://stackoverflow.co/company/careers/

Comment: I doubt it... I think only the person who wrote it might truly know what they meant to say.